# Android - Fitting 6 ImageButtons to layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, intellij-idea

I've been having a huge problem with fitting 6 image buttons to one screen.

I have tried Intellij and ADT but came up with nothing. I've also used two methods and played around them. One of them was inserting linear layouts to relative layout and inserting the image buttons inside them. This seemed well in the first place, however, i got bad results on big screens. The other method was to use regular alignment methods in xml but this gave me a lot worse results and I'm really stuck right now. I think I'm going to go with the first method but I want to get a good result since this is my senior project. You can find the two methods below. Can you help me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much.

**---EDIT---**

My intent is 3 lines, 2 buttons at each line. And screenshots are below. I have nexus 7 2013 and galaxy s2, and the results are similar to the ones below, so I assume the results below are correct.

This is the picture for 1st method:
[image: Method 1]

This is the picture for 2nd method:
[image: Method 2]

**---END OF EDIT---**

First method (inserting image buttons to 3 linear layouts in relative layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="390dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/apuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/apu"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/lmsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/lms"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp" android:layout_marginBottom="255dp" android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mailButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/mail"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/scaButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/sca"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="119dp" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginBottom="140dp" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/libraryButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/library"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/rating"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="127dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

Second method (using alignments):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/apuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/apu"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"


        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/lmsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/lms"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />



<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mailButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/mail"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/scaButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/sca"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/libraryButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/library"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/rating"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
```

Comment: do you have screenshots of what "bad results" are?

Comment: What exactly is your purpose? 2 lines, 3 buttons in every line?

Comment: check out my edit part :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/apuButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/lmsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mailButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/scaButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/libraryButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you very much! it seems i was somehow close to the solution :))

Comment: @Hardik4560,dear i'm not copied ans from your ans becz look at i change many things which is you can't know about it.

Comment: Anyways...It proves we think alike :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code, please comment if it works

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/grd_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/apuButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/lmsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mailButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/scaButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/libraryButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it didn't work because images dont have weight attribute

Comment: Dude, my answer is the same as the one you have accepted. Please don't give me the reason weight is not the attribute for images. Your question is about arranging the views not the image inside it.

Comment: yes, it is similar but weight is not accepted so i get error on intellij idea

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use your first method with linear layouts and add in weights so that it doesn't become separated out like that.  Here is the modified code of yours that should fix that issue (you'll want to create bigger images for each device so that it comes out looking a bit cleaner too).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/apuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/apu" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/lmsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/lms" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mailButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/mail" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/scaButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/sca" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/libraryButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/library" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/rating" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```